# Keeping Leading Zeros in a Number Field On PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to keep the leading zeros as the topic says. Here is my example:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEST_VIEW AS
    SELECT '00025' NUMBER1, 05 NUMBER2
    FROM DUAL;
```

I want NUMBER1 and NUMBER2 stored as 00025 and 05 in VARCHAR format but when I hit the query it stores that as 25 and 5.

I hope I could explain my problem and waiting for the replies.

Comment: for me it saved as '00025' and 5 respectively. The first field got data type as `CHAR(5)`, the second field got data type as `NUMBER`

Comment: Works just fine for me as well. Data returned as '00025' and 5. Are you sure this is the actual query and not "simplified"?

Comment: Returning 00025 and 5 is expected because Number1 is quoted and Number2 is not.  Also, your subject line states Number Field.  If you want leading zeros, you need varchar or char.

Comment: I want them both in Number format with leading zeros

Comment: What problem exactly are you trying to solve? By definition `00025` is a string of digits - what is the value of these digits? If they represent a decimal number, then the leading zeroes are insignificant and you can store them using the `NUMBER` datatype. If they are significant, the string is a string, NOT a decimal number, and you must use a character string datatype, e.g. `VARCHAR2`.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp I just want to store 00025 with the zeros in NUMBER format if it is possible.

Comment: That doesn't even make sense. Do you want to store the string of digits `00025` or do you want to store the number *value* `25`? These are two different things. Perhaps have a think about what this piece of data is supposed to represent. Is it a numeric value, or is it a code for something?

Comment: @Jeffrey I guess I should this issue with the project manager.

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEST_VIEW AS
    SELECT '00025' as NUMBER1, '05' as NUMBER2
    FROM DUAL;
```

Should be storing both `NUMBER1` and `NUMBER2` as strings.  The strings should have leading zeros.  Perhaps there is an issue with how you are querying the data.

Comment: I want to keep them in Number format. Thats my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `''` around your second number.  The first number should already be stored as a varchar.

Comment: I just wanted to show more examples thats why I wrote it like that. The problem is I cant keep them in Number format with leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

A view is only a stored SQL statement and does not persist any data.
when I ran your SQL and then selected from the test view, it returned as expected: the quoted string returned as a string and the number returned as a number (leading zeros trimmed).

```
select * from test_view;

NUMBER1  NUMBER2
-------  -------
00025          5
```

Leading zeros in a number field in Oracle are considered formatting and not provided unless asked for with formatting single row functions, for example:

```
select number1, lpad(number2, 2, '0') number2 from test_view;

NUMBER1  NUMBER2
-------  -------
00025    05
```

Comment: This returns String value but I want to keep them in Number format.

Answer (score 0):

> " I just want to store 00025 with the zeros in NUMBER format if it is possible"

It is not possible, Numbers are stored as NUMBER format, and rendered without leading zeroes. It you want to retain the leading zeroes then you need to store them as strings. This is because numbers `05 = 5 = 005` but strings `'05' != '5' != '005'`.

Alternatively you could handle this as a display issue. Store them as numbers but cast them as strings when you query them:

```
select lpad(to_char(25), 5 , '0') as number1
       , lpad(to_char(5), 2 , '0') as number2
from dual
```

Answer (score -1):

Confirming what Gordon, Jacob and Sudibta said, anyway if you want convert number and add leading zero, you can use:

```
SELECT SUBSTR('0000' || CAST(25 AS VARCHAR(5)),-5) AS NUM_LD_Z FROM DUAL
```

Comment: @APC You don't deserve any answer (I gave another possible solution...).  But there is people in the world who needs to feel someone giving (negative) votes and judging others... That's world.

Comment: For what it's worth I didn't down vote but then like you say some people feel the need to judge others ....

Comment: @APC: I didn't write you what you should do ("Don't confirm, upvote".  This is a judgement).  If you did not gave the vote, OK I'll consider it